# Ubuntu 16.04 GRUB recovery

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have installed Windows along with Ubuntu 16.04. After installed Windows, I can't navigate to my Ubuntu installation.

I tried with live repair,
booted Ubuntu 16.04 on my flash drive and tried to update grub according to
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
but I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ubuntu live CD (USB) a try this:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: can i use USB drive instead live cd ?

Comment: there is no different between LIVE-USB and LIVE-CD...